# proper way to use list to array?

Tags: java

```
public class TestClass{


private String divisions[] ={};


public void doAction(){

 Collection testArray = new ArrayList();
 // put testArray will data

  divisions = (String [] )  testArray.toArray(division);    //should i use this
 divisions = (String [] )  testArray.toArray(new String [] {});   //should i use this?

}

}
```

if i use case 1, and i call doaction multiple time, the division, something will show wrong records
if i use case2, divisions will always show the correct records.  is my assumption should use case 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in case 1 you could have a problem with extra items on the end of division.  Example: the first time you called doAction and division was set to a certain length then if the next time you called it, it needed less space, there would be extra items that did not get overwritten in the array.

However, case 2 is not all that useful because if the array you pass in (which has a length of zero in your example) is not large enough, ArrayList will just create a new array anyway.

Comment: so what is the proper way to use toarray    toArray(new String [] {})  OR  toArray(new String[list.size()])  ?

Comment: If you are creating a brand new array then toArray(new String[list.size()]) would create the correct size.  The other way would work as well it just might not be as efficient.  Case 1, is acceptable in situations where you want the data in an existing array, however in the example you presented this would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 is the "more correct" way to use it.

Essentially, you're telling the method what type you would like the resultant array.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the second one only

```
 divisions = (String [] )  testArray.toArray(new String [] {});
```